# Do Digital PS One games run on PS4?

Tags: ps4, psn

I have several PlayStation One (PSX/PSP) games that I bought digital from the PSN Store and downloaded/played them on PS3 and PSP.
Can I download them again and run them in PS4? Has anyone tried? Will the save file from my virtual memory card on PSP work on PS4? What about physical PSX discs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**  PS4 isn't backwards compatible, and given PS Now it might never be.

The only option to play anything other than PS4 games on a PS4 is PS Now.

Comment: Note that some PS1 and PS2 games can be bought on the PSN Store though